# Best evidence to offer a sandboxed appdomain for a C# evaluator

Tags: security, c#-4.0, appdomain

I have a c# evaluator which uses the (I think) the .Net 4 new simplified sandboxed appdomain model to host the c# assembly, with remoting doing the rest. The call to create the appdomain is

```
        Evidence ev = new Evidence();
        ev.AddHostEvidence(new Zone(SecurityZone.Trusted));
        PermissionSet pset = SecurityManager.GetStandardSandbox(ev);

        AppDomainSetup ads = new AppDomainSetup();
        ads.ApplicationBase = "C:\\Sandbox";

        // Create the sandboxed domain.
        AppDomain sandbox = AppDomain.CreateDomain(
           "Sandboxed Domain",
           ev,
           ads,
           pset,
           null);
```

The c# eval is embedded in a server app, but I don't want give the sandbox to much control unless it bo bo's the caller. What i'm looking for is regarding some clarification as to what to provide as Evidence from the caller.  I'm looking for advice and guidance.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: "to much control unless it bo bo's the caller" - What?

Comment: Nobody using sandboxed appdomains?

Comment: er.. no? :-) well at least I never run code I don't fully trust. Except python, which I never trust.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can either use the 'Internet' permission set or the 'Execution' permission set, both have limited permissions as they are deemed unsafe.

Comment: Thanks Adam, Seems we are the only two people using this method.

Comment: I don't use it, but it was covered in one of the MCTS exams - 70-536 I believe.  Glad it was useful for someone!