# App-domain evidence purpose?

Tags: c#, sandbox, appdomain, appdomainsetup

I've been looking into the app domain in regards to creating a simple lightweight app that will sandbox code i want to run for me. I have a simple console app which allows me to request the specified code to run and set permissions etc..

However i'm unsure of what exactly the evidence parameter does I've looked at multiple sources and a few books however it still seems hazy at least. In some places and code snippets null is used to create the sandbox and in others the app domain is created using the hosts actually evidence as a parameter.

So my questions are:

- what exactly does the evidence parameter do ?
- Is it needed / what does it do differently from permission set ?
- Should the sandbox user interface effect the evidence ?

  - As in is this a parameter which would require modification depending on .exe?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question?

Comment: I never found anything that definitive, however a few other post such as do shed some light on it:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2806729/best-evidence-to-offer-a-sandboxed-appdomain-for-a-c-sharp-evaluator